# In vuejs 2.5 form on key down to hide error

Tags: key, vuejs2

In my vuejs 2.5 form I show colored errors span in case of error

```
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label">Name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" v-model="newUserTaskType.name" v-bind:class="{'form-control':true, 'text-warning': errorsList.name}"
                               placeholder="Enter unique name of new user's task type" >
                        <small v-if="errorsList.name" class="text-warning">{{ errorsList.name[0] }}</small>
                    </div>
```

I want to clear this colored span in case key pressed on the input with error.
When I used Jquery I wrote a function like

```
setErrorKeypress: function () {
    $(".text-warning").bind('keypress', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("text-warning");
        ...
```

But it is not triggered now, if with erorr span has text-warning class.

I found a key handler like:

```
  <input v-on:keydown="keyhandler" />
```

But I dislike a way of setting an event in any input definition.

Could you give a ref/hint in which way this could be implemented ?

Thanks!

Hello,
let me ask 2 more questions on the theme:
I use VeeValidate for form validation and it worked ok.
But I decided to remake my editor using slot, like in resources/assets/js/components/lib/FormHelper.vue:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="form-header">
                <h3>Fill the form:FormHelper.vue</h3>
                <editor-header :show_loading_image="!is_page_loaded || is_page_updating" :header_title=title :message=message></editor-header>
            </div>

            <form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit" id="form_document_category_edit" class="form-horizontal">
                <div id="form-editable-fields">
                    <slot name="form-editable-fields"></slot>
                </div>

                <div id="form-button-controls">
                    <slot name="form-button-controls">
                        <div class="row pull-right">
                            <editor-buttons submit_label="Update" cancel_label="Cancel" :is_page_updating="is_page_updating"></editor-buttons>
                        </div>
                    </slot>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import appMixin from '../../appMixin';

    export default{
        created() {
        },

        mixins : [appMixin],

        mounted() {
        },  // mounted() {


        methods: {
            validateBeforeSubmit() {
                alert( "validateBeforeSubmit::"+var_dump(-1) )
                this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        alert( "Validated::"+(-9) )
                        this.updateDocumentCategory()
                        return;
                    }
                    alert( "False::"+(0) )
                })
            }, // validateBeforeSubmit() {
        }, // methods: {

        data(){
            return{
                title : 'Default Title',
                message : '',
                is_page_loaded:false,
                is_page_updating:false,
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

and using this helper in resources/assets/js/components/user_task_types/UserTaskTypesCreate.vue :

```
<template>
    <section>

        <form-helper  title="Password Reset" >

            <div slot="form-editable-fields">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label">Name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                            <input name="name" v-validate="'required'" type="text" v-model="newUserTaskType.name"
                                   :class="{ 'form-control':true, 'input': true, 'text-danger': vueErrorsList.has('name') }"
                                   placeholder="Enter unique name of new user's task type">
                            <span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('name')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('name') }}</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label">Description<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                            <textarea name="description" v-validate="'required'" v-model="newUserTaskType.description" rows="10"
                                      :class="{ 'form-control':true, 'input': true, 'text-danger': vueErrorsList.has('description') }"
                                      placeholder="Enter description of new user's task type"></textarea>
                            <span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('description')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('description') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- <div slot="form-editable-fields -->


        </form-helper>

    </section>
</template>


<script>
    import appMixin from '../../appMixin';

    import formHelper from '../lib/FormHelper.vue';  // resources/assets/js/components/lib/FormHelper.vue

    export default{
        components: {
            'form-helper': formHelper,
        },

        created() {
        },

        mixins : [appMixin],

        mounted() {
            this.setUserTaskTypeDefaultValue();
            this.loadUserTaskTypeDictionaries()
        },  // mounted() {

        data(){
            return{
                header_title : 'Create new user\'s task type',
                newUserTaskType:{
                    name:'',
                    description:'',
                },
                errorsList:[],
                message:'',
            }
        },
        methods:{

            createUserTaskType() {
                this.is_page_updating= true

                axios.post(window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/user_task_types', this.newUserTaskType).then((response) => {
                    this.errorsList= [];
                    this.is_page_updating= false
                    this.newUserTaskType = []
                    this.$router.push({path: '/'});
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.$setLaravelValidationErrorsFromResponse(error.response.data);
                    this.is_page_updating= false
                    this.showRunTimeError(error, this);
                });

            }, // createUserTaskType() {

            setUserTaskTypeDefaultValue() {
                this.newUserTaskType.name= '';
                this.newUserTaskType.description= '';
            },

            loadUserTaskTypeDictionaries() {
                this.is_page_loaded = true
            }, // loadDocumentCategoryDictionaries() {


        }
    }
</script>
```

1) When I click on a field with required option, I got error message ok, 
bluring the input I got error message as I need, as inputs are in UserTaskTypesCreate.vue file.

But when I click on submit function(calling validateBeforeSubmit)
validation does not work properly. Looks like validation object in the helper is different from validation objects in the 
UserTaskTypesCreate.vue  form. If there is a way some how to use the same validation object in both the form and the helper?

2) The helper has variable with default value

```
 title : 'Default Title',
```

Calling the for I set the title property as :

```
<form-helper  title="Password Reset" >
```

But it does not work and I see default value. Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to catch key press events of every inputs with validation.

**Removing `text-warning` class on key press of the input might be wrong.**

You might have validation rules on that input and user did wrong. So you are warning back user with error message. In that case, user might seems wrong if you remove the error class on key press. Better remove it on when user typed as correct as you ruled for that input.

I use [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/) to validate inputs with Vue. That will be more easy and saving time.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the link at vee-validate library.
Actually that is php/laravel/vue.js application.
Maybe these are old habits, but from prior php/javascript expierence I prefer to make data validation on server, considering
that validation on client's part in not safe. 

Is vee-validate library safe in this sense?
Or do you make validation both on client's part and on server's part?

Comment: Yes, I do make validation on both sides.

Comment: Yes, I starting working with this lib, what I did not find in demo and examples valid syntax for select and textarea controls. I tried to google  but failed to find working examples. Could you give links to  working examples ?

Comment: I found a way to check select and textarea controls : looks like I missed to add "name" tag. But if you make validation on both sides, how do you deal with errors messaging labels and tesing of validation rules? That looks somewhat tricky!

Comment: All of inputs are bounding with vmodel and submitting form in that way http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#validate-form . Post the ajax request if request is true. You need a setter for returned validation error messages from laravel. Error messages are being only used from vee-validator. What about using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate-laravel

Comment: I added 2 more questions, as update of 1st question. Thanks!